# Make scrollable div take up remaining height

Tags: html, css, scroll, flexbox, css-tables

I'm trying to make a page with a very simple layout: a header that stays in one place, and content that scrolls under it. The header div will be an unknown height that shows all of its content. I want the content div to take up all of the space between the bottom of the header and the bottom of the page AND to be able to scroll.

I have a couple of constraints on this:

- I don't want to use fixed or absolute positioning to keep the header in place, but rather have a div of the perfect height display the content, and have only that div be scrollable
- I don't want to set `max-height`, or any other property that requires knowledge of the height of the header div

The two methods that I have explored to achieve this are using a table layout and using a flex box. I have not managed to get scrolling working with either of these two methods. Below is the code for both attempts. I am using React. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!!

**EDIT**: I *did* do this successfully using inline styles and measuring the height of the header after it was generated. This worked on chrome on desktop, android chrome, and android browser, but it broke in ios safari. I don't know why it broke, and I am working on debugging, but I would prefer a cleaner solution that doesn't require inline styles. Thanks!

**the react element:**

```
var SimpleScrolly = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        var lorem = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet... ";
        var sampleText = lorem + lorem + lorem + lorem;
        var sampleHeader = "this is a header!"

        return(
            <div className={"simple_scrolly"}>
                <div className={"header"}>
                    {sampleHeader}
                </div>
                <div className={"content"}>
                    {sampleText}
                </div>
            </div>
            );
    }
});
```

**styling for table layout:**

```
.simple_scrolly{

  display: table;
  height: 100%;

  .header{
    display: table-row;
  }

  .content{
    overflow: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    display: table-row;
  }
}
```

**styling for flex layout:**

```
.simple_scrolly{

  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;

  .header{
    flex-grow:0;
  }

  .content{
    overflow: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    flex-grow:1;
  }
}
```

Comment: How about `$('.content).css({ 'height' : $(window).height() - $('.header').outerHeight() });`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Pejs !That's essentially what I was doing (although in react), and it worked on desktop, in android chrome and android browser, but broke in ios safari. It would be cleaner to do it without inline styles anyway, so I would prefer another option

Comment: Someone actually voted to close this question because "It does not seem to be about programming"  ?? WTF ???

Comment: @kat I actually don't see any problem with the formatting of this question. And it's actually a good question to ask!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It's actually quite doable without JS. You can easily do this with flex-box using a little "hack".

I worked on top of your flex box example, you can see it yourself in this little pen I made http://codepen.io/elleestcrimi/pen/LENQvr

The whole idea is  this:

1. The header has `flex-grow: 0 //This only fills up space as much as the content`
2. The content has `flex-grow: 1 //This way this fills up the space even if there is no content`
3. Place all the children of content into a new div called `#inner-content`
4. You absolutely place the `#inner-content` to fill up `#content`, and you allow it to scroll.
5. Tada!

Here is code below:

```
#header {
  flex-grow: 0;
}

#content {
  overflow: hidden;
  flex-grow: 1;
  position: relative;
}

#inner-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%; // this is needed if you are using any other element
}
```

Comment: its necessary to check the compatibility of flex-grow: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex-grow.asp

Comment: Worth noting perhaps that if the parent of the whole thing is not `body`, it must have `height: 100%`. That tripped me up for a bit.

Comment: This is not valid html. Please change your comment to use valid html5 and css.

Comment: Apparently inner-content can't be a table. I had to make it a div around my table.